# Spring Hibernate custom data return

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a table in mysql db called vehicles which has the following fields:id, model, type, onrent, etc...

I am using Spring with hibernate in my code with the n-tier design pattern (domain, repo, service).

I have the following query: `select Type, count(type) as Count from vehicles where onrent=true  group by type` which will return 2 columns: Type and the count on rent.

How should I get these data in my repo class having done my methods in the following way and where should I save the count:

```
public List<Vehicles> GetVehicles() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Vehicles> vehicles = session.createQuery("from Vehicles).list();
        return vehicles;
    }
```

If I used the above way, an error will be thrown telling me that no column was found called Count.

Comment: Hi Ali, this setup is a bit uncommon, to use Hibernate directly. I'd suggest to use spring data with jpa. Then you'll not even need to write qurey's like the getVehicle one. (BTW: in java functions start with lower case)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the javadoc from hibernate helps a bit out here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29

And the hibernate Reference is also a good resource of knowledge ;-):
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select